# Como abrir um navegador com Python, Selenium e o geckodriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, navegador-de-internet, instagram-api, geckodriver

Eu escrevi uma automatização para seguir pessoas no instagram, porém, quando coloco Run no código, ele me retorna no log com nenhum erro, e mesmo assim não abre o navegador para que eu teste o código. Acho que tem algo errado no inicio do meu código que não está permitindo abrir o navegador mas não sei o que pode ser. Esse é o código que estou utilizando para abrir o Firefox:

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o que esta faltando e inserir no código a url do site.

E logo após iserir a opção ex.: `web.get(url)`

segue um exemplo de código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://google.com/ncr")
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").send_keys("cheese" + Keys.RETURN)
    first_result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3>div")))
    print(first_result.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

fonte: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Espero ter ajudado.